# Не создаётся папка проекта Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm, установка

### Суть

Установил Django. Команда `django-admin startproject SFtutorial` выполняется. Папка с проектом не появляется. Повторный вызов команды возвращает `CommandError: 'C:\Users\Рибус\PycharmProjects\django-tutorial\SFtutorial' already exists`.

### Что делал

Создавал новые проекты и пробовал в старых. В глобальном поле видимости и в виртуалке. Устанавливал Django через терминал и через настройки интерпретатора. Кажется, перепробовал вообще всё, что мог только представить. В итоге решил, что возможно я или в ходе этих разбирательств, или даже ранее наломал каких-то дров в PyCharm'е. Поэтому принял решение полностью удалить с компьютера Python и PyCharm и попробовать с нуля. Далее по шагам то, что я делал с самого-самого начала.

1. Установил Python 3.8.10 (у меня Windows 7) и PyCharm Community Edition
2. Перезагрузился.
3. Запустил PyCharm.
4. Создал проект. Виртуалку не активировал, она подрубилась автоматически.
5. Выполнил в терминале `pip list` для успокоения души. Чисто.
6. Установил Django через терминал командой `pip install Django==4.0.5`.
7. Проверил, установился ли Django, командой `pip show Django`. Установлен, находится в *venv*.
8. Создал проект командой `django-admin startproject SFtutorial`. Команда выполнилась без ошибки. Проект не создался. Повторное выполнение той же команды приводит к ошибке `CommandError: 'C:\Users\Рибус\PycharmProjects\django-tutorial\SFtutorial' already exists`.

Помимо вышеуказанного не делал ничего, чтобы случайно что-нибудь не сломать.
В проводнике папка проекта также не отображается.

### Скриншоты процесса

[Ссылка](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bp7Di0K6sQIeNGpgnyye2MLo6HkuCbU4?usp=sharing) на Google-Диск.

### Терминал

Всё, что я вводил и получал в терминале:

```
    Windows PowerShell
(C) Корпорация Майкрософт, 2009. Все права защищены.

(venv) PS C:\Users\Рибус\PycharmProjects\django-tutorial> pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        22.1.2
setuptools 62.3.3
wheel      0.37.1
(venv) PS C:\Users\Рибус\PycharmProjects\django-tutorial> python install Django==4.0.5
C:\Program Files\Python 3.8.10\python.exe: can't open file 'install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(venv) PS C:\Users\Рибус\PycharmProjects\django-tutorial> pip install Django==4.0.5
Collecting Django==4.0.5
  Using cached Django-4.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (8.0 MB)
Collecting backports.zoneinfo
  Using cached backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (38 kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
  Using cached sqlparse-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting tzdata
  Using cached tzdata-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (339 kB)
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.4.1
  Using cached asgiref-3.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Installing collected packages: tzdata, sqlparse, backports.zoneinfo, asgiref, Django
Successfully installed Django-4.0.5 asgiref-3.5.2 backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1 sqlparse-0.4.2 tzdata-2022.1
(venv) PS C:\Users\Рибус\PycharmProjects\django-tutorial> python show Django
C:\Program Files\Python 3.8.10\python.exe: can't open file 'show': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(venv) PS C:\Users\Рибус\PycharmProjects\django-tutorial> pip show Django
Name: Django
Version: 4.0.5
Summary: A high-level Python web framework that encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design.
Home-page: https://www.djangoproject.com/
Author: Django Software Foundation
Author-email: foundation@djangoproject.com
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: c:\users\рибус\pycharmprojects\django-tutorial\venv\lib\site-packages
Requires: asgiref, backports.zoneinfo, sqlparse, tzdata
Required-by:
(venv) PS C:\Users\Рибус\PycharmProjects\django-tutorial> django-admin startproject SFtutorial
(venv) PS C:\Users\Рибус\PycharmProjects\django-tutorial> django-admin startproject SFtutorial
CommandError: 'C:\Users\Рибус\PycharmProjects\django-tutorial\SFtutorial' already exists
(venv) PS C:\Users\Рибус\PycharmProjects\django-tutorial>
```

### UPD 14.06

Я обнаружил, что команда `django-admin startproject SFtutorial` создаёт *скрытую* папку и отправляет проект туда: `C:\VTRoot\HarddiskVolume2\Users\Рибус\PycharmProjects\django-tutorial`. Я попробовал создать проект задав полный путь к нужной мне папке: `C:\Users\Рибус\PycharmProjects\django-tutorial`. Но это ни на что не повляло, проект всё равно создал скрытую папку в том же месте.

Теперь я понял, что проект создаётся. Создаётся он у чёрта на куличках. Как это исправить?

### UPD 03.07

Вопрос не решён, но не актуален. Починил старый ноут, отформатировал диск, поставил свежую Лубунту. Дальше по инструкции. Всё заработало сразу без плясок с бубном.

Comment: Путь к другой папке пропиши попробуй.
В командной строке напиши dr <путь к другой папке>.

Comment: @AirGuy, пробовал, результата не давало. При любых раскладах проект улетал в скрытую папку.